# How to join an array of strings?

Tags: swift, carriage-return

I am having problems attempting to return elements of a String array line by line within a textView. I have indeed used the special carriage return character in my code sequence to return elements of the array on separate lines. However, I have not been able to succeed thus far. Here is a code snippet of what I typed:

```
txtViewQuestionStatus.text = "\(numCorrect) correct Answers, However these are the questions answered INCORRECTLY: \(model.incorrectItems())\n" //Have text view present number of correct answers and list incorrect Questions line by line.
```

What could I be doing wrong in my source code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `model.incorrectItems()` returning? Can you post that part of your code? If it returns an array of strings you can join them like so:

```
"... INCORRECTLY: \(model.incorrectItems().joinWithSeparator("\n"))\n"
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you very much Stijn van der Laan.